# Strings from letters A,B,C

Tags: combinatorics

I got stuck on a simple problem which is part of a bigger problem.
So OK... All strings of length n from the letters A,B,C are $3^n$.

But how many of them contain at least one A and at least one B and at least one C ?!

I am getting $3^{n} - 3 \cdot 2^{n} + 3$ when I apply the inclusion-exclusion principle.

But I am not sure in this answer.

Comment: Looks good.  In general, a good way to check is to try it for small $n$, where you can compute the answer by hand.

Comment: This is also $\left\{n\atop3\right\}\cdot3!$, where $\left\{n\atop3\right\}$ is a [Stirling number of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind) that counts the number of partitions of $n$ objects into $3$ non-empty subsets: Partition the positions in the string into three non-empty subsets and assign the $3$ letters to them in one of $3!$ different ways. As you can see in [this section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind#Simple_identities), this coincides with your result.

Comment: Thanks, guys. I just wanted to make sure I don't have a mistake here. I found my mistake, it was in another part of the solution of the bigger problem. Thanks again.